# Невозможно обработать SyntaxError

Tags: python, python-3.x

Невозможно обработать

```
try:
    def f()
except SyntaxError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ошибки синтаксиса отлавливать нельзя, так как они генерируются не во время рантайма. 
Разве что вот так:

```
try:
    eval('def func()')
except SyntaxError:
    print "You cannot do that"
```

Answer (score 3):

Словить `SyntaxError` можно только из `eval`, `exec`, `import`.

Comment: В дополнение к ответу [ссылка на документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SyntaxError)